# React Native:Positioning does not work and images positioned below viewing area

Tags: css, react-native, view

On android emulator, my React Native 0.62.2 app displays uploaded images within an accordion whose display area is warped with `<View>` which is styled with `width and height`. The image is warped with  which is `<Image>` with cache ability. The problem is that the image is positioned way below beyond the viewing boundary and is not visible when open the accordion.

Here is the render code in accordion which is provided with both width and height as canvas:

```
return (
    <>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => toggleListItem()}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotateZ: arrowAngle }] }}>
            <Icon name="chevron-down-outline" size={20}  />
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.bodyBackground, { height: bodyHeight }]}>
        <View
          style={(absPosition ? styles.bodyContainerAbs : styles.bodyContainerCenter), (screenSize ? {width:screenSize.width, height:screenSize.height, flex:1} : null)}
          onLayout={event => {
            if (screenSize) {
              setBodySectionHeight(screenSize.height);
            } else {
              setBodySectionHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height);
            };
            console.log("layout : ", event.nativeEvent.layout);
          }
          }>  //<<<===here is <View> warping the image area. Both width and height are set.
          {children}  //<<<===images uploaded displayed here
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </>
  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bodyBackground: {
    backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  bodyContainerCenter: { //<<<==here is the style used for display images 
    padding: 1,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  bodyContainerAbs: {
    padding: 5,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
  },

});
```

Here is the image render code:

```
const displayImg = (img_source, width, ht, index) => {
        if (img_source && img_source!==[] && img_source!=={}) {
            return (
                <ImageZoom  cropWidth={screen_width}   
                            cropHeight={screen_ht}
                            imageWidth={width}
                            imageHeight={ht}
                            enableSwipeDown={true}
                            style={{padding:1}}
                            >
                    <FastImage 
                        source={{uri:img_source}} 
                        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain} 
                        style={{ //<<<===image width and height are set
                            width:width, 
                            height:ht, 
                            position:"absolute" //<<<===does not work
                        }}
                    />
                </ImageZoom>
                );
        } else {
            return null;
        };
        
    };
```

When there is one image, it is display with full screen width. For 2 images, then they are displayed side by side occupying half of the screen width:

```
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
const DisplayImages = ({pics}) => {
        if (!pics || pics===[] || pics==={}) return null;
        var len = pics.length, 
        if (len > 0) setImgAccordOpen(true);
        switch(len) {
            case 0:
                return;
            case 1:  //<<<=== one image is uploaded
                
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      {displayImg(pics[0].path, screen_width*full, screen_width*full, 0)}
                      </React.Fragment>
                    );
            case 2:  //<<<=== case of 2 images uploaded
                return (
                    <Grid style={{position:"absolute", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                        <Row style={{paddingTop:0}}>
                            <Col style={{position:"absolute", top:0,left:0, paddingVertical:0}} > //<<==positioned at [0,0] on up left corner.
                            {displayImg(pics[0].path, screen_width*half, screen_width*half, 0)}
                            </Col>
                            <Col style={{position:"absolute", top:0,left:Math.ceil((screen_width-20)/2), paddingTop:0}}>  //<<==positioned at [0, middle of screen]
                            {displayImg(pics[1].path, screen_width*half, screen_width*half, 1)}
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                );             
    .....
```

Here is the screen shot when one image is uploaded. The image is not positioned at `absolute`

[image]

Here is the screen shot when 2 images are uploaded. The first image is not within the viewing area and not visible at all.

[image]

How to position images right within viewing area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `<ImageZoom>` is not compatible with `<FastImage>` and only show a portion of image or positioning images way below the viewing screen. After removing `<ImageZoom>`, then the position of the images is back to normal as style dictated. Another module `@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view` works fine with `<FastImage>`.